# Environment stays Local when deploying Laravel to Heroku

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to set dev + production environment in Laravel 5, but when i check the current environment - i get Local in both cases...when i work local and when i deploy to Heroku...

I want to create the 2 environments for switch from https to http smoothly...

Here is the AppServiceProvider.php file...

```
<?php

        namespace App\Providers;
        use App;
        use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

        class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
        {

            public function boot()
            {
                $environment = App::environment();
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($environment); // prints Local - always
                echo '</pre>';
                die();
                if (App::environment('production', 'staging'))
                {
                    \URL::forceSchema('https');
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "environment=", App::environment(), "\n";
                }
            }

            public function register()
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

And here is the .env file

```
        APP_NAME=Laravel
        APP_ENV=local
        APP_KEY=base64:foo
        APP_DEBUG=true
        APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
        APP_URL=http://localhost

        DB_CONNECTION=mysql
        DB_HOST=foo
        DB_PORT=3306
        DB_DATABASE=foo
        DB_USERNAME=foo
        DB_PASSWORD=foo

        BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
        CACHE_DRIVER=file
        SESSION_DRIVER=file
        QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

        REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
        REDIS_PASSWORD=null
        REDIS_PORT=6379

        MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
        MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
        MAIL_PORT=2525
        MAIL_USERNAME=null
        MAIL_PASSWORD=null
        MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

        PUSHER_APP_ID=
        PUSHER_APP_KEY=
        PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: Change `APP_ENV=local` to `APP_ENV=production` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `.env` file on your Heroku server to reflect that it's production. You should keep your `APP_ENV=local` on your local development machines, but change it to `APP_ENV=production` on your live server and `APP_ENV=staging` on your staging server.

Edit:

In the root of your local server, you must have a `.env` file that has `APP_ENV=local` in it (the rest can stay as above in your question). On your production server, you must have the same `.env` file, but change `APP_ENV=local` to `APP_ENV=production` and also edit the database connection data if required. You don't need any additional files/folders, `.env` files are *environment specific*.

And then this code will work fine (look at my comments)

```
$environment = App::environment();
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($environment); // prints Local - always - but this won't when you have the 2 differing environment files
echo '</pre>';
die();

if (App::environment('production', 'staging'))
{
    \URL::forceSchema('https');
}
else
{
    echo "environment=", App::environment(), "\n";
}
```

Because you have *separate* `.env` files on *each* server. They are **not** meant to be committed inside a repository, they *must* be different and in the root of the project.

Comment: Thanks - how can i switch environments smoothly? can i set .env file for production and another for local? how and where should i create the method that will do it? thanks.

Comment: @RoyBarOn The .env is per machine, your local .env doesn't get tracked in version control, you have to set different .env files per environment. Your server has one .env file with the above code, your local machine has another .env with the local production, thats all you need to do

Comment: @RoyBarOn did you get it sorted?

Comment: not so sure i got it - suppose i create 2 env files - where and how can i do the checking  and the switching of the files? i need a method that doing - "production? - good - let's run /production/env. local? - good - let's run /local/env." ....

Comment: @RoyBarOn You already have the check in your code, all you need to do is do the 2 environment files as I've said... `if (App::environment('production', 'staging'))` is already checking the environment...

Comment: Please just create a `.env` file in your local machine and then create another `.env` on your production server and change the `APP_ENV` as stated in my answer, the system will do the rest as your code already checks for the difference in `APP_ENV` @RoyBarOn

Comment: @RoyBarOn I have updated my answer, if you do the above your problems will be sorted. This is how Laravel is meant to be used between servers/environments.

Comment: @RoyBarOn Any news on the implementation?